# How can I use python to filter the json with AWS list pricing API?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

I want to filter the json that operatinSystem are linux ,and I have some problem with it,the part of json in

```
 '' : {
```

that I don't know how dictionary represent it and

```
"DQ578CGN99KG6ECF" : {
```

how can I represent it with wildcard, anyone could help my please.

```
import json
import urllib2
response=urllib2.urlopen('https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json')
url=response.read()
urlj=json.loads(url)
filterx=[x for x in urlj if x['??']['??']["attributes"]["operatingSystem"] == 'linux']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the wildcard representation. I'll look into it and get back to you. Meanwhile, I have already worked with this json before so I can tell you how to access the information you need.
The information you need can be obtained as follows:

```
for each_product in urlx['products']:
    if urlx['products'][each_product]['attributes']['operatingSystem']=="linux":
        #your code here
```

If you need pricing information from the json you need to take the product code string and look into the priceDimensions field for it. Look at the sample json and code accordingly.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/

Comment: When I use "operatingSystem" it failure,but "servicecode"  worked,I don't know what the reason is?                                                                        if urlj['products'][each_product]['attributes']["operatingSystem"]=="linux":
KeyError: 'operatingSystem'

Comment: This might be because "operatingSystem" key is present only for compute instances. So you can check whether the product you are dealing with is a compute instance or not like this:
if each_product["productFamily"]== "Compute Instance"
or check if "operatingSystem" key is present like
if "operatingSystem" in urlx['products'][each_product]['attributes'].

Put either of these conditions before the if condition in the answer